# ANT create the jar file giving problems with getResource + encoding

Tags: java, ant, encoding, build, jar

I am creating my build.xml file to build my jar with ant.

All is perfect except for the load of external resources as images.

All I want to do is understand how create in the right way the jar. actually my code is:

I know that the problem is on each line that contains:
this.getClass().getResource("/img/logo150.png")
(I am shure about this because I tested each one alone with logging and debugging, the problem is in that)

but I can't understand why. I tried hundred of possibilities, many different settings of the jar, I tryed many different answers here in stackoverflow but no solution have worked.

I am using eclipse and the folder structure is:

```
src -> source code
res -> img -> images
res -> config.files.txt
db -> database files
lib -> libs
```

any idea about it? the code work perfectly if I run the project, but when I run the ant build (Run as) it doesn't work.

EDIT: oh yeah finally I can post the code!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Garby Gestore Clienti" default="try_jar" basedir=".">
    <description>
    This buildfile is used to build the jar of the program.
    </description>

    <!-- ================== Property Definitions ===================== -->
    <property file="${user.home}/Garby.properties" />
    <property file="${user.home}/.Garby.properties" />
    <property file="${basedir}/Garby.properties" />

    <!-- ================= File and Directory Names ==================== -->
    <property name="src" location="${basedir}/src" />
    <property name="build" location="${basedir}/build" />
    <property name="dist" location="${basedir}/dist" />
    <property name="app.name" value="Garby" />
    <property name="dist.jarHome" value="${user.home}/Garby" />
    <property name="app.version" value="1.0" />
    <tstamp />
    <property name="jar.name" value="${app.name}_${app.version}.${DSTAMP}.jar" />
    <property name="jar.completePath" value="${dist.jarHome}/${jar.name}" />



    <!-- Here you must specify the directory in which jar files needed by this plugin to run are stored  -->

    <property name="shared.lib" value="${basedir}/lib" />

    <!-- =============== Custom Ant Task Definitions =================== -->
    <property name="compile.debug" value="true" />
    <property name="compile.deprecation" value="false" />
    <property name="compile.optimize" value="true" />

    <!-- ================== External Dependencies ======================= -->
    <property name="Database" value="hsqldb.jar" />

    <!-- ================== Compilation Classpath ======================= -->

    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <!--<pathelement location="${src.home}"/>-->
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <include name="**/*.java" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${shared.lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- =================== All Target ================================ -->

    <!-- ================== Try_jar Target ============================ -->
    <target name="try_jar" depends="compile, dist, signjar, clean_class_files, run" description="Clean build and dist directories, then compile, create and sign jar and finally run Core.jar" />

    <!-- ================== Clean Target ============================== -->

    <target name="clean" description="Delete old build and dist directories">
        <delete dir="${build}" />
        <delete dir="${dist}" />
    </target>

    <!-- ================== Prepare Target ============================= -->

    <target name="prepare" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build}/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="${build}/lib" />
        <copy todir="${build}/lib">
            <fileset dir="${shared.lib}" includes="${Database}" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- ================== Compile Target =========================== -->

    <target name="compile" depends="prepare" description="Compile Java sources">

        <mkdir dir="${build}/classes" />
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/classes" encoding="8859_1" debug="${compile.debug}" deprecation="${compile.deprecation}" optimize="${compile.optimize}" source="1.7" target="1.7">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- =================== Dist Target ================================ -->
    <target name="dist" description="Creates Jar archive">
        <!-- Create the time stamp -->
        <tstamp>
            <format property="compile.timestamp" pattern="yyyyMMddHHmm" />
        </tstamp>
        <!-- update core version in manifest -->
        <replaceregexp file="${basedir}/manifest" match="Implementation-Version: .*" replace="Implementation-Version: ${app.version}.${compile.timestamp}" />
        <!-- Create Jar file -->
        <jar destfile="${jar.completePath}" manifest="${basedir}/manifest">
            <fileset dir="${build}/classes" excludes="**/*.bak" />
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/bin"/>
            <zipfileset src="${shared.lib}/${Database}" />
        </jar>

        <copy todir="${dist.jarHome}/db">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/db" includes="**" />
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${dist.jarHome}/res">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/res" includes="**" />
        </copy>


    </target>

    <!-- ================== SignJar Target ============================ -->
    <target name="signjar" description="Signs jar with keystore taken from your shared.lib folder">
        <!--<signjar jar="${jar.completePath}" keystore="${shared.lib}/paripari.jks" alias="irc" storepass="${keystore.password}" keypass="${private.password}"/>-->
    </target>

    <!-- ================== Javadoc Target ============================ -->

    <target name="javadoc" depends="compile" description="Create Javadoc API documentation">

        <mkdir dir="${dist}/docs/api" />
        <javadoc sourcepath="${src}" destdir="${dist}/docs/api" packagenames="*">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
        </javadoc>

    </target>

    <!-- ================== RmBak Target ============================= -->

    <target name="rmbak" description="Delete *.bak files everywhere">

        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${docs}" includes="**/*.bak" />
            <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.bak" />
        </delete>

    </target>

    <!-- ================== RmLog Target ============================= -->

    <target name="rmlog" description="Delete *.log files from build directory">

        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${build.home}" includes="**/*.log*" />
        </delete>

    </target>
    <!-- =================== Delete .class Target===================== -->
    <target name="clean_class_files" description="Delete .class files stored inside build directory and dist folder">
        <delete dir="${build}" />
        <delete dir="${dist}" />
    </target>

    <!-- ================== Run Target =============================== -->
    <target name="run" description="Run Garby">
        <java jar="${jar.completePath}" fork="true">
        </java>
    </target>

</project>
```

Second question:

```
encoding= 8859_1
```

this line is not written by me. but I am having problem with the encoding (in the jar I can't see the euro simbol) what king of value should I set?

third

Is there any "correct" or "standart" folder structure for a java project (in eclipse also) or I am going well with mine? (also many different paths)

Comment: Can't download the file, it requires an account.

Comment: Include the output of `ant build`, at least the part with error message.

Comment: there are no error, the only problem is that getResource can't load the file.

Comment: I solved **PART** of the problem, I added a <fileset dir="${basedir}/bin" /> inside the <jar> tag. Now the program can read the internal resources called with getClass().getResource().
My problem now is to read resources that are NOT inside the jar file. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like this:

```
<copy todir="${yourJarFolder}/folder">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/folder" includes="**" />
</copy>
```

This code copy a folder that you have in your workspace directly in the folder of your jar, not inside the jar, but the same folder.

After that you can access any resources with the standard method not using getResource().

Hope it work for you.